# android How to set Gravity in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gravity

I'm trying to make a chat app, and having a trouble with setting gravity of custom view in the RecyclerView. I've been searching and trying a whole day, but i couldn't make, it always shows like [this(ScreenShot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C82iv.png).It should be located right of screen not left. But in Android Studio Preview, It shows correctly.Im attaching my source.. please tell me what's wrong..

1. In MainActivity.xml (RecyclerView)

   ```
   ......
   <RelativeLayout
       android:background="#9cbad8"
       android:layout_weight="70"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_transparent"
       android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
       android:paddingTop="50dp"
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   .......
   ```

2.In  MessageItem.xml (I set graivity Right, and screenshot shows correctly)

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_normal_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/my_time"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="오후 15:15"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:maxWidth="200dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bubble_my"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:text="this is Test"
                        android:id="@+id/my_normal_text" />
            </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Android Layout Preview shows well(ScreenShot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQYEF.png)

3. My RecyclerViewHolder

   ```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       LinearLayout myLayout;
       LinearLayout myNormarLayout;
       LinearLayout myMoreLayout;

       public ViewHolder(View v) {
           super(v);
           myLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
           myNormarLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.my_normal_layout);
           myMoreLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.my_more_layout);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Also in my RecyclerViewAdapter, I changed Gravity Again..

   ```
   ....
   holder.myNormarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.myNormarLayout.setGravity(Gravity.Right);
   ....
   ```

I had tried almost of things from searching, but they didn't work for this..
please... help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Constraint Layout for better performance.

In your case maybe adding a weighted view between the time and  text could help, try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_normal_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/my_time"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="오후 15:15"/>
                <View
                      android:layout_height="0dp"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_weight="0"
                      />
                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:maxWidth="200dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bubble_my"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="this is Test"
                    android:id="@+id/my_normal_text" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My bad, I changed something on the parent layout, check again copy paste, all I changed is adding the View between the 2 text views.

Comment: Tahnks but i just tried , it doesn't work it is still located to left ..

Comment: My Main Activity.xml shows like this, [link](http://imgur.com/a/Ppr8K) and is that related to this problem??

Comment: Don't think so. Maybe put the whole project on github, and I can try to fork it, and do a fix.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!! I just uploaded on Github. When you have time, please check, Thank you again!  [uploadedLink](https://github.com/pmw188/test)

Comment: Thank you sosososososo much!!